# How to view/debug the interaction between the terminal and the shell?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I understand that the terminal intercepts control-codes as listed by `stty -a`, and that the shell (Bash) utilizes the Readline library to process its input, which it receives buffered after each key-press.

Furthermore, the shell should communicate Readlines changes to the terminal by means of terminal control codes. But how does the terminal communicates control-codes e.g. `^W` (delete word backwards) to to the terminal?

In order to see this, I would like to debug the terminal-shell interaction. How can I do this?

Comment: "But how does the *terminal* communicates control-codes e.g. ^W (delete word backwards) to to the *terminal*?" – I suspect a typo here, isn't the first one supposed to be "shell"?

Comment: `^W` is listed in the output from `stty -a` and so relates to the terminal and not the shell? Shell commands are defined by Readline, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To examine the communication in the shell -> terminal direction, the easiest is probably to record the stream using `script(1)` and then examine the log file.

This does not include the communication in the other direction (keypresses), nor side channel operations (terminal `ioctl`s corresponding to the `stty` command).

(If you need to include these as well, probably you should `strace` the application or debug what the terminal emulator exactly does.)

You'll notice that there's no such thing as e.g. `^W` (delete word backwards) in the shell -> terminal direction. There are simpler primitives only, e.g. moving the cursor by a specified amount of cells, or printing (overwriting) characters. They can't behave differently depending on a character cell containing a letter or a space, and as such, the concept of "word" doesn't exist here.

Comment: Thanks @egmont. I thought that `script` was used only to record command-line(s)? How does the terminal inform the shell of `stty`-related `ioctl`'s it receives, like `^W` (delete word backwards)? In this case, the shell must be informed, so that there is a common agreement regarding the terminal's state or content? Furthermore, do you know a good resource describing terminal-shell interaction in detail?

Comment: `script` records whatever the application running inside produces. You may run another shell inside it, or specific tools, as you wish.

Comment: "How does the terminal inform the shell of stty-related ioctl's it receives" – it doesn't.

Comment: But, how is the shell aware of what command line to execute, when the user presses ENTER? The shell receives streamed input from the terminal through a buffer; if the user had pressed `^W`, then the command line, that will be executed by the shell, will differ from that on the terminal?

Comment: What have I misunderstood?

Comment: There are two different major modes: cooked and raw. In cooked mode (e.g. when `cat` is running) the kernel handles `^W`, it's typically bound to `stty werase` and the kernel erases a word. In raw mode (e.g. when at the shell) the shell receives `^W` and does whatever it wants.

Comment: Do all shells operate in raw mode, or are there exceptions? In particular, does Bash operate in raw mode? How can I verify whether the shell runs in raw mode or not?

Comment: In my terminal (`gnome-terminal`) running Bash, I can use `^W` to delete a word backwards (Readline has no mapping for that key-combination) on the command line, so Bash runs in cooked mode in this case?

Comment: Cooked mode only provides the very basic line editing experience that you get at `cat`, e.g. no left/right arrows. Anything more complex than that needs to be raw mode. In `bind -P`'s output you'll find `^W`.

Comment: I'm sure there's tons of great documentation on this topic, and I hope I managed to give you enough start to continue exploring this area yourself.